# How do I properly organize my inheritance classes to take advantage of polymorphism?

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance, polymorphism

I am trying to redesign my item class. I am having trouble picturing how things should work.

**Current implementation:**

```
class Item : public QGraphicsItem
{
public:
    typedef enum  { PolygonType = QGraphicsItem::UserType + 1 } ShapeType;
    Item() {...} 
    Item(const Item &copyItem) // copy constructor
    {   m_shapeType = copyItem.getItemShape();
        m_color = copyItem.getItemColor();
        setPos(copyItem.pos()); ...}
    QRectF boundingRect() const;
    QPainterPath shape() const;
    void setItemShape(ShapeType s) { m_shapeType = s; }
    ShapeType getItemShape() const { return m_shapeType; }
    int type() const { return m_shapeType; }   // this will replace the above to allow QGraphicsItem casts
    void setItemColor(QColor c)    { m_color = c; }
    QColor getItemColor() const    { return m_color; }
    ....
protected:
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option,
               QWidget *widget);
    QColor m_color;
    ShapeType m_shapeType;
    ....
};

QPainterPath Item::shape() const
{
    QPainterPath path;
    switch (m_shapeType)
    {
    case Item::PolygonType:
        ...
        break;
    ....
    }
}
QRectF Item::boundingRect() const
{
    return QRectF(...);
}
void Item::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem */*option*/, QWidget */*widget*/)
{
    switch (m_shapeType)
    {
    case Item::PolygonType:
            painter->drawPolygon(shape().toFillPolygon());
            break;
    ....
    }
}
```

Based on selections, I create an item and add to a canvas... then once all changes have been made, I add it to a `QGraphicsScene`.

**Required tasks:**

The processing of the scene contains iterations of the type

```
Item* item1 = new Item(*renderArea->item);
// make some changes on the item copy, then add it to a scene
collectionView->scene()->addItem(item1);

// in another function...
for(int i = 0; i < collectionView->scene()->items().size(); ++i)
{        
    Item* item = new Item(*(dynamic_cast<Item*>(
                           collectionView->scene()->items().at(i))));
   ...
}
```

**What I am trying to achieve**

This is a minimal approach, but I have to extend functionality to items that extend other classes, like `QGraphicsPixmapItem` (without having to add a pixmap to every item that does not need it) or `QGraphicsSvgItem` (again, without having to add so much overhead to items that don't need it).

So what I am trying:

```
class PolyItem : public Item
{
public:
    PolyItem(): Item()
    {
        m_shapeType = Item::PolygonType;
    }
    PolyItem(PolyItem& copy): Item::Item(copy)
    {
    }
    virtual void paint(QPainter* painter,
                       const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem* option,
                       QWidget* widget = NULL)
    {
        painter->drawPolygon(shape().toFillPolygon());
    }
};
```

or

```
class PixMapItem : public Item, public QGraphicsPixmapItem
{
public:
    PixMapItem(): Item()
    {
        m_shapeType = Item::PixmapType;
        setShapeMode(QGraphicsPixmapItem::BoundingRectShape);
    }
    PixMapItem(PixMapItem& copy): Item::Item(copy)
    {
        setPixmap(copy.pixmap());
        setShapeMode(QGraphicsPixmapItem::BoundingRectShape);
    }
    virtual void paint(QPainter* painter,
                       const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem* option,
                       QWidget* widget = NULL)
    {
        painter->drawPixmap(boundingRect(), pixmap());
    }
};
```

**The question:**

- How do I make it work ? How do I create instances of PolygonItem when I choose a shape (and still be able to use the generic Item to modify other properties, like color ?)

-----> I was thinking of making a different constructor that creates the correct shape, in class Item - but that seems to mean that Item requires class polygon that requires class Item... circular dependency ?

- Even more complicated, how can I perform the tasks above, modifying a generic item, iterating through items, regardless of shape ?

What I can't visualize:

`collectionView->scene()->addItem(item1);`

If my item is of polygon type, will the `Item::paint()` function - and all the other associated functions - be called, or the `PolyItem::paint()` ?
Do I have to insert switch-case code to determine and cast every single instance, of every single type ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably it worth to reduce your Item class to BaseItem containing everything you are adding to an Item yourself, and all functions you expect any Item to have (as pure virtual if they cannot be implemented without QGraphics*):

```
class BaseItem {
public:
    void setItemColor(QColor c)    { m_color = c; }
    QColor getItemColor() const    { return m_color; }
    ....
protected:
    QColor m_color;
    ShapeType m_shapeType;
};
```

Then

```
class Item : public BaseItem, public QGraphicsItem
class PixMapItem : public BaseItem, public QGraphicsPixmapItem
```

and so forth - avoiding circular dependencies. Any Item can be referred to as BaseItem, and provides common interface defined by BaseItem. Each child provides specialization of that interface to proper QGraphics*.

Problem with your original design is that item inherited from QGraphicsItem while it shouldn't, since you plan further specialize it for QGraphicsPixmapItem, which contains QGraphicsItem in itself already.

**Edit**

Now, you treat all items as BaseItem when you iterate through them - which means that BaseItem has to provide an interface all Items adhere to. Given examples you provided in your question, one way to do it:

```
class BaseItem {
  virtual void AddToScene(QGraphicsScene* scene) = 0;
  // Caller takes ownership.
  virtual BaseItem* CreateCopy() = 0;
};
```

Required tasks:

The processing of the scene contains iterations of the type

```
BaseItem* item1 = renderArea->item->CreateCopy();
// make some changes on the item copy, then add it to a scene
item1->AddToScene(collectionView->scene());
```

Each derived class *implements* interface defined by BaseItem, while you treat all Items as BaseItem in your generic operations. That also makes code easily extensible - adding new Item type only requires implementing derived class, but existing code stays as is - so BaseItem needs to be carefully designed to provide interface for operations common for all items.

```
class Item : public BaseItem, public QGraphicsItem {
      void AddToScene(QGraphicsScene* scene) override { scene->addItem(this); }
      // Caller takes ownership.
      BaseItem* CreateCopy() override { return new Item; }
};
```

Comment: This is how I am thinking it - but doesn't `class PixMapItem : public Item, public QGraphicsPixmapItem` also contain `QGraphicsItem` twice ? therefore it should be enough to further specialize the pixmapitem and svgitem classes on top of the existing Item class ? (or technically i is better to make the `BaseClass` - as an interface ?)

Comment: Also... I still do not understand how to use the items, will I have to cast them to the most childish class before using hem (i.e. adding them to a canvas) ?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo - I meant BaseItem.

Comment: I am sorry, I just don't see it - the only difference I see in this example is that you removed the dependency of `Item` on `QGraphicsItem`. That will no longer allow a `scene()` to recognize `Item` objects - so I can no longer add generic items to a `scene()` or iterate through the `scene()` items and extract the `Item` types. So this has even less functionality - and as for creating items of proper type, there is no way.

Comment: @Thalia Expanded a bit

Answer (score 1):

Creating different objects depending on a runtime decision is a typical use case for the [Abstract factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern). In your case you can have:

```
class ItemFactory
{
public:
    virtual Item* create() = 0;    
};
```

And then:

```
class PixMapItemFactory : public ItemFactory
{
public:
    PixMapItemFactory(/* possibly some configuration parameters */);
    Item* create();  // will return a PixMapItem instance
};
```

Then you can operate on `ItemFactory*` type, not knowing nor caring what's the particular type you're creating. It will return `Item*` instances, so you can change their common properties regardless of their concrete instance type.

Comment: How do I work with the `Item*` ? will I be able to use the functionality I depicted - iterating through `items()` collection and casting them as `Item*` ? And if I cast as `Item* `and the `Item` happens to be a `PixmapItem` type, will it have the functionality of the `PixmapItem` ?

Comment: @Thalia You don't need to cast them as `Item*` - they will be of `Item*` type already. Your code should not explicitly cast `Item*` to subtypes. Implement common method in `Item` and those that very in behaviour as `virtual`/abstract in `Item`, and override them in subclasses.

Comment: Will the functions of the child items be used ? I just don't know how to ask this - it really is the ONLY question I have. If I use the 'QGraphicsScene` to manipulate items, will the parent or child `paint()` methods be used ? When I add an item to a scene, do I have to know what item type it is, or will the child be added even though I am asking for the parent to be added ?

Comment: @Thalia Any simplest tutorial on polymorphism in C++ answers that question in all possible ways. If the methods are virtual, the method of the actual object will be used, regardless of pointer type. So if `Item*` points to an object of type `PixMapItem`, methods from `PixMapItem` will be used.